# I created 4 EC2 and created 2 target group each having 2 EC2. i created the load balancer and created the rules as per snippet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

if I am launching the Load balancer **DNS only** then I am getting the output but as per rule if I am adding the text. getting **invalid URL**

[image: having the text images as per rule]

[image: DNS of load Balancer]

[image: created rules of load balancer]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your webserver on the instances doesn't host anything on `/images.html`. ALB only matches the path with `forward` rules, and base on the match it forwards to different targets. It does not do any modifications of the path. Your instalnces still need to be able to handle full path, in your case `images.html`

You may try `redirect` rules, as they allow for some customization of the query.

Comment: Thank u for response, But I have created the rule if URL is like */images* then navigate to the Image-TG target. what is the way then to do it.

Comment: @RoshiMalik If your instance already responds to `/images`, you don't need any rules. The default rule is fine. What ever rule you create, it must be valid rule for your web application.